# Crypto.JS with AES Default Key Expansion - Decrypt in Java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

Helo guys, a client application is using the [cryptoJs Library](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS) for AES Encryption

in the following way:
`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "SampleKey123456"`)
From the documentation:

> For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV.

The Java Server is using JDK8 + JCE

Questions:

- Will the IV be prepended to the Encrypted String (first 16 Bytes)? I guess not, because it says: `derive an actual key and IV`
- How can I use the same Key Expansion in Java or which algorithm is it?I've got the Passphrase `"SampleKey123456"` as Plain Text and would use `new SecretKeySpec(keyPlain.getBytes(), "AES")` if it was the actual key instead of Passphrase
- Another Idea would be using a standard Key Expansion/Derivation function like pbkdf, which could easily be used in cryptoJs and Java.

Comment: cryptojs's key derivation [seems to be](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS/blob/master/components/evpkdf.js) a joke (1 round of md5). Definitely use pbkdf2 or scrypt.

Comment: I know, sadly the client application is not in my responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a spring-security-crypto compatible Version:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertwiesner/14Lhapv0/
It uses PBKDF2 with Password and Salt

```
var password = $("[name='password']").val();
var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse($("[name='salt']").val());
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {
keySize: 256 / 32,
iterations: 1024
});
```

In Spring: `return Encryptors.standard(cryptoPassword, new 
    String(Hex.encode(Utf8.encode(cryptoKeySalt))));` where cryptoPassword and cryptoKeySalt are regular String properties.

Will post a full example on GitHub, soon.